# opengl es position after glRotatef and glTranslatef

Tags: android, opengl-es

i'am new in OpenGL ES. Can you helps me to calculate world coordinates of cube after rotate and translate. For example:
first i rotate cube:
gl.glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0);
than change his position
gl.glTranslatef(10, 0, 0);

How can i calculate his "new" world coordinates? I read about glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX , matrix) but not understand it. Maybe someone can provide sample code.
**EDIT:**

I found solution. Android code

`float[] matrix = new float[] {

1,0,0,0,

0,1,0,0,

0,0,1,0,

0,0,0,1,

};

Matrix.rotateM(matrix, 0, rx, 1, 0, 0);

Matrix.rotateM(matrix, 0, ry, 0, 1, 0);

Matrix.rotateM(matrix, 0, rz, 0, 0, 1);

Matrix.translateM(matrix, 0, x, y, z);

x = matrix[12];

y = matrix[13];

z = matrix[14];`


Thanks for answers.

Comment: If you're looking for the cube's new position you're most likely doing something wrong. That matrix stuff is intended to make drawing easier (allowing you to draw stuff at different positions without having to recalculate everything by hand). I wouldn't use it to calculate game logic. Any more details on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Recommend read this -http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~kapaho/CG/06_3d_trans.pdf#page=21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have an answer for the part you want, in terms of the rest of your question, you'd do something like (please forgive me if I make any Java errors, I'm not really an Android person):

```
float[] matrix = new float[16];

gl.glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrix);

// check out matrix[12], matrix[13] and matrix[14] now for the world location
// that (0, 0, 0) [, 1)] would be mapped to
```

That getFloatv just reads back the current value of the modelview matrix into the float buffer specified. In OpenGL 4x4 matrices are specified so that index 0 is the top left, index 3 is the lowest number in the first column and 12 is the number furthest to the right in the first row. That's usually referred to as column-major layout, though the [OpenGL FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm) isn't entirely happy with the term.